# ssh Authentication failed on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I tried to ssh a remote linux server with username and password on my Mac. But it shows the following mistake. It seems that it tries to login with rsa keys. But I want to login with password. (I can successfully login with password in Xshell in windows)

SSH command:

```
ssh -v -p 10022 qhdxliy@42.123.106.11
```

Debugging output:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 42.123.106.11 [42.123.106.11] port 10022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version     OpenSSH_100.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_100.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 42.123.106.11:10022 as 'qhdxliy'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:iqMu6xmkaocbmHW4ejr0REqMGiIBVgaBz4CkocSwopI
debug1: Host '[42.123.106.11]:10022' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/zhaokai/.ssh/id_rsa
Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're invoking ssh. Are you running it interactively? Are you running some program or script that launches ssh? Is this running from cron or some other non-interactive process?

Comment: I run it interactively. etene's ansower has solved my problem.

Comment: Marking it as accepted would be nice then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password auth is tried after the public key. If you don't want your ssh client to try your public key first, use the `PreferredAuthentications` option, i.e.

```
ssh -o "PreferredAuthentications=password" [other options... ]
```

Source: the `AUTHENTICATION` section of ssh's manual page states:

> The methods available for authentication are: GSSAPI-based authentication, host-based authentication, public key authentication, challenge-response authentication, and password authentication.
>        Authentication methods are tried in the order specified above, though PreferredAuthentications can be used to change the default order.